# Issue in ajax code, not refreshing page after the 30 seconds

Tags: ajax, jquery

With the help of someone here i got to this point with the code.
I need to reload a div without refreshing it..

Here is the code:

```
function LoadContent()
{
    $('#lista').load('pagination.php');
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    LoadContent(); //load contentent when page loads
    setTimeout('LoadContent()',30000); //schedule refresh
});
```

But this ain't working..
Can someone please help me with this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't need document.ready() to load function, You just call the function.

```
    LoadContent(); //load contentent when page loads
    setTimeout('LoadContent()',30000); //schedule refresh
    function LoadContent()
    {
        $('#lista').load('pagination.php');
    }
```

Comment: Oh well, the issue is, i can't use it like this because the div won't appear right away, it will take 30 seconds for it to appear...
i need the pagination.php to appear imemdiately and for it to refresh every 30 seconds..

Comment: then you use setInterval() instead of setTImeout()

Answer (score 0):

Try the following,
    int = setInterval(function() {LoadContent();}, 30000);..
If u want stop refresh at any time u can do by int = window.clearInterval(int);